# Determine repository license canonically

Tags: github

GitHub's free repositories are for open source software.

Is there a canonical way in GitHub user interface to identify what OSS license a project is under?

Answer (score 1):

Since [September 2016](https://github.com/blog/2252-license-now-displayed-on-repository-overview), GitHub displays the license, *if recognized*, at the top of the repository, next to the number of contributors:

[image]

---

**How are licenses recognized?**

It's quite common for repositories to have an unrecognized license. There may be several reasons for that.

GitHub uses the open source project [Licensee](https://github.com/benbalter/licensee) to detect licenses. Common reasons for unrecognized licenses include:

- Licensee can only recognize licenses from [choosealicense.com](https://choosealicense.com/) with slight differences.
- The license needs to be in its own file, ideally `LICENSE` or `LICENSE.md`. Mentioning or writing the full license in the README is insufficient.
- Titles and addendums (in addition to any already in the original license) often prevent Licensee from recognizing the license.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually no way to visually identify the license in one single eyeshot. By the way, most of repo ( I mean nearly all of them ) have a `README.md` file with in most case some words about licensing.

Comment: This was [changed in 2016](https://github.com/blog/2252-license-now-displayed-on-repository-overview) thanks to the open source project Licensee.